# unable to import object from one folder to folder which i am in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

[image]

I am trying to import a file from other folder
but got this error

```
./src/components/Body/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../context' in '/home/workspace/reactjs/coding-practices/layoutBuilder/src/components/Body'
```

I have tried:

```
 import ConfigurationContext from '../../context'
 import ConfigurationContext from './../context'
```

i am in  `Body>index.js`   want to import object from `context>ConfigurationContext.js`

Please help to resolve this quesion

Comment: What is inside the `context` folder? You need to have `index.js` in that folder to import it like this

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import ConfigurationContext from './../../context/ConfigurationContext'
```

because you didn't mention the file name in path.